# Controversy over products of iodate and bisulfite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

We know that when we are trying to recognize iodate, we use sodium bisulphite to the solution and with the help of starch paper recognize the evolved $\ce{I2}$.But when I studied the books I found actually Iodide is formed? What's the solution to this controversy?

Answer (score 3):

Not much controversy here, IMO. There is more than one reaction involved, with slightly more complex kinetics.

As so often, Wikipedia already knows, so I will just quote the relevant part of the following article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction

> Iodate variation
>
> An alternative protocol uses a solution of iodate ion (for instance potassium iodate) to which an acidified solution (again with sulfuric acid) of sodium bisulfite is added.
>
> In this protocol, iodide ion is generated by the following slow reaction between the iodate and bisulfite:
>
> $$\ce{   IO3^{−} + 3 HSO3^{−} -> I^{−} + 3 HSO4^{−}}$$
>
> This is the rate determining step. The iodate in excess will oxidize the iodide generated above to form iodine:
>
> $$\ce{   IO3^{−} + 5 I^{−} + 6 H+ -> 3 I2 + 3 H2O}$$
>
> However, the iodine is reduced immediately back to iodide by the bisulfite:
>
> $$\ce{   I2 + HSO3^{−} + H2O → 2 I^{−} + HSO4^{−} + 2 H+}$$
>
> When the bisulfite is fully consumed, the iodine will survive (i.e., no reduction by the bisulfite) to form the dark blue complex with starch.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site, which makes questions and answers more easily readable.

Comment: @Philipp: I appreciate your tip - but have you ever tried typing this way on a tablet? This is just not going to happen - some formatting shortcuts/buttons would be quite useful...